# Система обновления приложения qt c++

Tags: c++, qt

Подскажите, возможно ли создать такую систему обновлений, которая не будет сверять всё приложение с сервером, а обновлять только конкретные части приложения, только те, которые были изменены. Пишу само приложение на qt c++

Comment: Можно. Надо разделить приложение на подключаемые/обновляемые библиотеки и не забыть про бинарную совместимость

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно можно. Разбейте свой проект на несколько библиотек, компилируйте каждую в отдельную dll/so, считайте их контрольные суммы (тот-же md5), отправляйте на сервер имена+суммы+ОС, получайте список ссылок, выкачивайте и заменяйте. Учтите, кстати, что под некоторыми ОС исполняемый файл себя удалить не сможет, придётся хитрить.

Но.

Я считаю такое поведение (самостоятельное обновление) устаревшим и не нужным в современном мире. Дело в том, что всё сейчас переходит на пакетное управление. Даже в windows уже есть свой магазин, несколько кустарных пакетных менеджеров (например, [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/)).

Поэтому всё-таки я вам советую не тратить силы на разработку "обновлятеля", а научиться пакетизировать своё ПО под нужные ОС.

Comment: Заставлять пользователей ставить chocolatey (при всей моей любви к этому менеджеру, сам пользуюсь) это не совсем правильно. Как минимум на винде системы автоматического обновления сильно распространены, логично рассматривать такой способ.

Comment: Там недаром написано "Например". Никто не заставляет.